# Выровнять блок со второго ряда, к блоку первого ряда. Grid css

Tags: css, grid

Как выровнять `div` к верху вне зависимости от высоты рядов? На моем примере: прилепить `div` (с текстом 4) к `div`, который находиться выше него. Нашла что то про "mansory", но кажется это немного другое.

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.main div {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ff7e7e;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid #ffdd83;
}

.center_block{
height: max-content;
}

.grid_column_item {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="center_block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of</div>
  <div class="grid_column_item">4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вы ищете действительно называется "mansory". К сожалению браузеры пока не поддерживают `grid-template-rows: masonry;`

https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_grid-template-rows_masonry

На данные момент только FF с включенной опцией умеет отобразить это свойство `layout.css.grid-template-masonry-value.enabled` = true

Выглядеть будет вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока что ищите другие варианты сделать то что вам надо.

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: masonry;
}

.main div {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ff7e7e;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid #ffdd83;
}

.center_block{
height: max-content;
}

.grid_column_item {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="center_block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of</div>
  <div class="grid_column_item">4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант конкретно под 5 колонок:

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.main>* {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main>*:not(.center_block) {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ff7e7e;
  border: 5px solid #ffdd83;
}

.center_block div {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ff7e7e;
  border: 5px solid #ffdd83;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="center_block">
    <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
</div>
```

И еще вариант, с абсолютным позиционированием:

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.main div {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ff7e7e;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid #ffdd83;
}

.center_block {
  height: max-content;
}

.grid_column_item {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="center_block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of</div>
  <div class="grid_column_item">4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А через flex нельзя такое сделать?

Comment: Если рассматривать конкретно ваш случай, то можно добавить обертку вокруг центрального блока и не парится. Я добавил в ответ.

Comment: Нет, мне html структуру нельзя нарушать )

Comment: @АннаМатвеева, добавил еще вариант с абсолютным позиционированием. Но опять же, это не универсально